# jQuery - Why will a button appended to a document not fire?

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I apologize if this question is a duplicate.

I am attempting to append to a DIV a button that will fire another jQuery script. However, I can not get the appended button to fire. I'm curious to know what I am doing wrong. I have attempted to unbind and use 'on' rather than 'click' and I'm still having issues.

You can see my Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Y82ZK/1/

When you click the 'Add' button the Remove Button will not fire. For some reason my Firefox Firebug is being of any assistance to me today.

The code being used in the JS fiddle:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" />
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var count = 0;
$('#add').click(function(){
   count++;
$('#container').append('<div class="section' + count + '">This is count ' + count + '. <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove" /></div>');

});

$('#remove').click(function(){
   var row = $(this).attr("class");
   $(row).remove();
   count--;

});
```

Any ideas on why appended button will not fire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you should change your code from this:

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click','#remove', function(){
```

Comment: to explain why: `.click()` will never bind to elements that don't exist on the page at load. `$(document).on()` will bind the event to all child elements of the `document`, even if they're added after the page has loaded. jQuery API for on: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @yochannah Thank you for that extra information. This fix did the trick I needed. When I attempted something similar earlier it appears that I had a typo which made me think this method was not working. I appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody explained why, ill do it.

Let start with the base. Using `$('#remove').click()` is the same of using `$('#remove').on('click', function(){})` which is the prefered way of binding event.

But using event like that are binding direct event. That mean it add the event on the element itself. It is much faster than the delegated event (ill come to it later) but has the disadvantage that the target element **must be present when applying the binding**. Hence, that's why we use DOM ready handler before binding.

Delegated event are the other kind of events. we use it like that : `$(document).on(click, '#element', function(){})`. `document` should be the closest static (not added dynamicly) element for performance gain. This type of event bubble from the target (`document`) and get the children target containing the event.

It is in fact slower since it is not direct, but it has the advantage of working on dynamic elements.

More information here : http://api.jquery.com/on/

To answer your question, you can either do :

```
$('#container').append('<div class="section' + count + '">This is count ' + count + '. <input type="button" id="remove" value="Remove" /></div>');

$('#remove').click(function(){ //Bind the event after adding it.
    var row = $(this).attr("class");
    $(row).remove();
    count--;

});
```

Or add the delegated event :

```
$('#container').on('click', '#remove', function(){
    var row = $(this).attr("class");
    $(row).remove();
    count--;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the event when you create the element.

**JS**

```
var count = 0;
$('#add').click(function () {
    count++;
    var removeButton = $('<div id="section' + count + '">This is count ' + count + '. <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" /></div>');
    removeButton.click(function () {
        this.remove();
        count--;
    });
    $('#container').append(removeButton);
});
```

#### jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/Y82ZK/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use event delagation. Try:

```
$("body").on('click', '#remove', function(){
   // stuff here
});
```

Comment: miss the identifier '#' on "remove"

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$('#remove').click(function(){
```

Will hook the click action to any element with the ID `#remove` when the JS code is run, this will not target any dynamically added elements, you need to use the

```
$(document).on('click','#remove', function(){
```

method, this will actively poll your HTML for any new elements with the ID `#remove` that appear, allowing you to hook the click functionality to the dynamically appended element.

Answer (score -1):

You probably shouldn't use same IDs as IDs must be unique for each element. Use classes instead to perform selections

Comment: Possibly true, but that's not why the code doesn't work, it's due to @Ryan using .click() rather than on()